# A pendulum's rope swings and strikes a peg

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

So I have this problem, as far as I can tell I solved it correctly, and it's not equal to any of my answer choices.  The problem is:  A rope of length $L$ is attached at one end to a ceiling and at the other to a mass.  The mass is held taught horizontal to the ceiling and then released.  When the rope is completely vertical, it strikes a peg located a distance $d$ straight down from the pivot point.  What is the minimum distance $d$ that would cause the mass to travel in a (smaller) circle after the rope hits the peg?

Now at first I really didn't even understand what it was asking--it seems to me like *any* distance would cause the mass to swing along some circular path, reach a maximum height, and fall down again.  But I guess what it's asking is really:  What is the minimum distance for which the mass will travel completely around in a circle?  In that case, I can see that when the mass reaches its maximum height on the smaller circular track, gravity is just balancing with centripetal acceleration so that $a=g=\frac{v^{2}}{r}$ or in this case $\frac{v^{2}}{L-d}$.

Moreover if we say that the bottom of the mass's trajectory is 0 potential energy, then the total energy at the start is $mgL$ and all forces in the system are conservative.  So when the mass reaches the top of the small circle, we get the energy equation

$$mgL = mg(2d) + \frac{1}{2} mv^{2} \Longrightarrow$$

$$gL = 2gd + \frac{1}{2}g(L-d) \Longrightarrow $$

$$L = 2d + \frac{1}{2}L-\frac{1}{2}d \Longrightarrow $$

$$\frac{1}{2}L = \frac{3}{2}d \Longrightarrow$$

$$d = L/3$$

Every step I've made seems so clear to me, but if anyone can point out a mistake I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question, distance $d$ is measured from the pivot down:

> [...] a peg located a distance $d$ straight down from the pivot point

You have computed it from the bottom of the swing up. I expect that $d = \frac{2L}{3}$ is one of the answers in your list...

Your analysis is otherwise correct. One word of advice: ALWAYS draw a diagram. If you show that you are computing a different $d$ you might get most of the credit. Of course "multiple guess" questions don't really ask for diagrams. They should be forbidden in physics classes. Just saying.